# Magento 2 - Delete store view

Tags: magento2, php, admin, magento2.3, multistore

I want to delete Admin website from my website, but if I delete my admin is not accessible anymore. Any ideas how I can delete that Admin Store safe?

[image]

This is my database:

**store** table
[image]

**store_group** table
[image]

**store_website** table
[image]

Comment: Any idea what the store ID of that store is?

Comment: You can try to first delete `Store View`, `Store` and then `Web Site`.

Comment: hi @Pawan thank you for your suggestion, but if I press on Admin in the Store View  section I see this error: Store view doesn't exist.

Comment: Hi @DominicXigen I just edit my post, can you check please? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure you can fix this without affecting the integrity of your database.

The correct configuration is this.

`store`

[image: https://i.snag.gy/PFdWH9.jpg]

`store_group`

[image: https://i.snag.gy/yd0JRE.jpg]

`store_website`

[image: https://i.snag.gy/3HKW2w.jpg]

Try manually editing database to match above